# How to retrieve $_SESSION value in a JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

I have this working script yet when I change it to retrieve(supposedly) the value inside `$_SESSION["username"]`, it doesn't retrieve anything. The whole page is saved as .php as I am using some codes that uses PHP.

Code:

```
echo "<script type=text/javascript>";
echo "var hidden = false;";

echo "function actiondb1() {";
echo "if(!hidden) {";
echo "document.getElementById(\'clickdb1\').style.visibility = \'hidden\';";
echo "document.getElementById(\'db1\').style.visibility = \'visible\';"; 
echo "document.getElementById(\'db1\').disabled = false;";
echo "document.getElementById(\'db1\').value =".$_SESSION["username"];.";";

echo "}";
echo "}";
echo "</script>";
```

How can I make the script to properly retrieve the data inside `$_SESSION["username"];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Havenard mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25396514/1525594), this line is missing Javascript single quotes to properly denote a string variable:

```
echo "document.getElementById(\'db1\').value ='".$_SESSION["username"];."';";
```

However, you really shouldn't print JS out with PHP if you can help it. Though [iatboy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25396561/1525594) answer won't ultimately fix your bug, it is a **much** cleaner way of doing things.

```
?>
<script type=text/javascript>;
var hidden = false;
function actiondb1() {
  if(!hidden) {
      document.getElementById('clickdb1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById('db1').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
      document.getElementById('db1').disabled = false;
      document.getElementById('db1').value ='<?php echo $_SESSION["username"];?>';
    }
}
</script>;
<?php
```

Comment: The idea of closing the `php` tags before this sequence and opening it again after the code block works, Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! You could also look into the `heredoc` PHP syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that, for instance, if the value of `$_SESSION["username"]` is `John`, your `echo` will be generating this result:

```
document.getElementById('db1').value = John;
```

But John is supposed to be a string and should be wrapped in quotation marks, otherwise JavaScript will understand it as a variable name (which value will be probably `undefined`).

Answer (score 0):

Did you start session in this page?If you didn't,use the follow code to start session.

```
    session_start();
```

Then change your code to

```
echo "<script type=text/javascript>";
echo "var hidden = false;\n";
echo "function actiondb1() {\n";
echo "alert('".$_SESSION['username']."')\n";  //test code
echo "if(!hidden) {\n";
echo "document.getElementById('clickdb1').style.visibility = 'hidden';\n";
echo "document.getElementById('db1').style.visibility = 'visible';\n"; 
echo "document.getElementById('db1').disabled = false;\n";
echo "document.getElementById('db1').value ='".$_SESSION["username"]."';\n";
echo "}\n";
echo "}\n";
echo "</script>";
```

it will be ok.